# Is side-effect operator allowed in C expression with more than a variable?

Tags: c

I am trying to use side effect operator in my expression which does not have just a variable. My program was compiled successfully but I got a runtime error "Segmentation fault"

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    printf(1 + (x++));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `printf` must be a format string.  Try `printf("%d\n", 1 + x++);`

Comment: `char *x = "?Hello World!\n";` is worth a try as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C requires you to format the string, this way it knows what it should print. What you have in your example is nothing but memory addresses, which makes the C compiler confused.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", (1 + (x++)));

    return 0;
}
```